# Como verificar o retorno de uma função

Tags: php, phpmailer

Galera montei uma função que executa a classe *phpmailer* e envia um e-mail. Porém não sei como verificar o retorno dela e saber se o e-mail foi enviado. Bom segue a função:

```
    function envia_email($destinatario) {

        // Aqui fica todos os dados da função


        // Envia o e-mail
        $email->Send();
    }
```

O que envia o e-mail e esse comando `$email->Send();`.

E eu chamo a função assim:

```
envia_email($destinatario);
```

Bom, como eu faço para saber se deu true ou false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É preciso analisar a biblioteca que esta utilizando, dê uma olhada na documentação dela e veja o retorno de `send()`.

Porém, caso esteja utilizando `PHPMailer` que é de costume geral utilizar você pode observar aqui:

> Creates message and assigns Mailer. If the message is not sent successfully then it returns false. Use the ErrorInfo variable to view description of the error. Returns true on success, false on failure.

Este método ele retorna `true` ou `false` para o envio. Sendo assim, você pode utilizar este retorno.

```
function envia_email($destinatario) {

    // Aqui fica todos os dados da função


    // Envia o e-mail
    return $email->Send(); // true or false
}

$retorno = envia_email($destinatario);

if($retorno === false){
   throw new Exception('Email não foi enviado.');
}
```

Simples.

Comment: ok, funcionou 100% muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Ela retorna True ou False:

```
if(!$Email->Send()) {
   echo A mensagem não foi enviada.";
   echo Mensagem de erro: " . $Email->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Mensagem enviada!";
}
```

Mais detalhes do funcionamento da classe aqui:
http://www.devmedia.com.br/enviando-e-mail-com-o-phpmailer/9642

Comment: eu sei, mas o que eu quero e verificar com a função, ou seja que o `$Email->Send()` retome false ou true na função entendeu.

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso esse código, funciona bem e relata os erros.

```
if(!$email->Send()) :
$mensagemRetorno = 'Erro ao enviar formulário: '. print($email->ErrorInfo);
else : 
echo"<script>alert ('Email enviado!')</script>";
endif;
```

Comment: eu sei, mas o que eu quero e verificar com a função, ou seja que o `$Email->Send()` retome false ou true na função entendeu.